# PowerBI : is there a cloud equivalent to the ReportServer PBI tables?

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi, microsoft365

I use Power BI on premise, and I am used to query the sql-server ReportServer database to retrieve useful informations on those tables :

- dbo.Catalog (reports)
- dbo.ExecutionLogStorage (reports usage audit)

Now, I am also using cloud-based PowerBI (Azure/365), and I know I can get informations by using Power BI REST APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/).
That is sadly not a very satisfying solution for many reasons (admin rights requirements, bad performances ...).

I would like to be able to do the same thing I do on Power BI on premise, but on the cloud version, which leads to these questions :

- Is there a cloud database containing the same tables as on premise Power BI ?
- Is it possible to list Azure databases and then tables from Azure databases ?
- Is there a different way to retrieve those informations (PBI report and audit informations) ? I know it is possible to query the Unified audit log for Power BI auditing, but it suffers from the same issues as the Power BI REST APIs AND it doesn't provide the report informations (dbo.Catalog).

Thanks !